# How to define many-to-many relation with existing table with Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, many-to-many, tortoise-orm

I have the following models (and an enum) defined:

```py
from tortoise import models, fields
from enum import Enum

class WorkspaceUserRole(str, Enum):
    owner = "owner"
    collaborator = "collaborator"

class User(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)

class Workspace(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)

class WorkspaceUser(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", "workspace_users")
    workspace = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Workspace", "workspace_users")
    role = fields.CharEnumField(WorkspaceUserRole)
```

I would like to do something like:

```py
user = ... # fetch a User
workspaces = await user.workspaces.all()
```

But that relation does not exist. Adding it to User obviously conflicts with the
existing `workspaceuser` table.

How do I perform this query, or add the relation to the User model?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have worked:

```py
from tortoise import models, fields
from enum import Enum

class WorkspaceUserRole(str, Enum):
    owner = "owner"
    collaborator = "collaborator"

class User(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    # Added the following relation:
    workspaces = fields.ManyToManyField(
        model_name="models.Workspace", through="workspaceuser"
    )

class Workspace(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)

class WorkspaceUser(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", "workspace_users")
    workspace = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Workspace", "workspace_users")
    role = fields.CharEnumField(WorkspaceUserRole)
```

This enables both:

```py
await user.workspaces.all()
```

and:

```py
await workspace.users.all()
```

Comment: this is not working if you have several tables M2M relationship...and want to use the same through table for all